# Reading the nth element from a file

Tags: c++

I have a text file with one column of numbers. There are about 500 numbers within the column. How would I only read the nth number. For example, is there a way to read and store the 49th number in the column?

Comment: Start reading, start counting.  When you reach 49, stop.

Answer (score 1):

if the numbers are fixed size (you don't show a sample file) then you can seek to size * n and read. Otherwise just do a read, parse, count loop till you reach n

Answer (score 1):

If they're stored as text, so the space occupied by each number can vary, you're pretty much stuck with either reading through them until you get to the correct point, or else using a level of indirection--that is, creating an index into the data itself.

For the former, you could (for example) store each number as a 32-bit binary number. On a typical machine that means every number occupies 4 bytes, so getting to the N<sup>th</sup> item, you multiply N by 4, seek to that point in the file, and read 4 bytes.

If you want to store the numbers as text, but still support seeking like this, you could pad every number with spaces so they all still take up the same amount of space in the file (e.g., 10 characters for every number).

If you really want to avoid that (or have a pre-defined format so you can't do it), then you could create an index into the file. This makes sense primarily when/if you can justify the cost of reading through the entire file and storing the position of the beginning of each line. There are at least two obvious justifications. One is that the indexing can be separated from usage, such as building the index in a batch at night to optimize use of the data during the day. The other possibility is simply that you use the data file enough that the savings from being able to seek to a specific point outweighs the time to index the file once.

There are less obvious justifications as well though--for example, you might need to meet some (at least soft) real-time constraints, and if you read through the file to find each item, you might not be able to meet those constraints--in particular, the size of file you can process can be limited by the real-time constraints. In this case, an index may be absolutely necessary to meet your requirements, rather than just an optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Adding verbosity to @pm100's answer (perhaps unnecessarily), the fixed size means same ascii count.

```
001
01
```

Line `001` takes up 3 bytes while `01` only takes up two.
Thus if your file has numbers formatted like this:

```
1
2
3
100
10
```

Using lseek (or fseek) would only work if each column entry has the same number of ASCII chars for each line (as far as I am aware).
Also you need to keep track of the `\n` character if you go this route too.
`lseek(fd, size * n *  2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
ifstream fin("example.txt");
std::string line;

for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  std::getline(fin, line);
}
// line contains line n;
```